# Passing json data from jquery to flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, flask

I'd like to pass some Json data from jQuery to flask. I have an add user method which takes some form values and passes them to flask.

```
function kullaniciEkle(event) // add a user
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var hataSayisi = 0;

    $('#addUser input').each(function (index, val) {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            hataSayisi++;
        }
    });

    console.log("Number of errors: ", hataSayisi);

    if (hataSayisi === 0) {

        var yeniKullanici = {
            'kullanıcıAdı' : $('#kullaniciEkle fieldset input#girisIsim').val(),
            'eposta' : $('#kullaniciEkle fieldset input#girisEposta').val(),
            'tamİsim' : $('#kullaniciEkle fieldset input#girisTamIsim').val(),
            'yaş': $('#kullaniciEkle fieldset input#girisYas').val(),
            'yer' : $('#kullaniciEkle fieldset input#girisSehir').val(),
            'cinsiyet' : $('#kullaniciEkle fieldset input#girisCinsiyet').val()
        }

        console.log(yeniKullanici);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(yeniKullanici));

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(yeniKullanici),
            url: '/add',
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Are we here?");
                $('#kullaniciEkle fieldset input').val('');


            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });

    } else {
        alert("Please fill in all form fields");
    }

}
```

And the add method in flask is like that.

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def addUser():
    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.get_json(silent=True)
        print (content)
        return 'Hi there'
```

It looks like I may get the json data from flask. But on the jQuery side I suppose error part is executed. Because I get an alert message 'Hi there' if addUser() function returns this value or if it returns empty alert message if returned value is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataType` parameter in the ajax call tells jQuery what type to expect back from the server. You've specified `json`, but you are not returning JSON from the Flask handler so jQuery throws an error.

Either actually return JSON, or remove that parameter.